# Usar strpos en una variable con PHP

Tags: php

El siguiente ejemplo me indica si el texto de la variable **$frase** contiene una **S** como letra.

```
$frase="respuesta en ingles";
$posicion_coincidencia = strpos($frase, s);
if ($posicion_coincidencia === false) 
{
echo "La $frase";
} else {
echo "Las $frase";
}
```

Mi pregunta: Lo que yo necesito del texto de la variable $frase es:

Si no contiene la letra **(S)** en el final de la primer palabra me muestre en pantalla **(La $frase)** y si en cambio contiene la letra **(S)** en el final de la primer palabra me muestre en pantalla **(Las $frase)**.

Es decir me muestre (LA o LAS) dependiendo si hay (s) o (no) en la primer palabra de la frase indicada.

Espero que me entiendan. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Necesitas separar la frase y chequear el ultimo caracter de la primera palabra.  Puedes hacerlo utilizando `explode` y `strlen` asi:

```
<?php

$frase="respuesta en ingles";
$palabras = explode(' ', $frase);
$ultima = strlen($palabras[0]);
$posicion_coincidencia = $palabras[0][$ultima - 1];
if ($posicion_coincidencia !== "s") 
{
echo "La $frase";
} else {
echo "Las $frase";
}
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu ayuda me sirvio de mucho. Muy amable de tu parte. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Y si la frase es: `Una respuesta para Andrés` cómo se manejaría la situación?

Comment: Tu ejemplo no tiene sentido.  La pregunta se trata de agregar s o no a una frase e iniciar una oracion concatenando La o Las.  "La Una respuesta para Andres" no cabe en este caso.

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurren dos formas posibles:

#### Alternativa #1: expresión regular.

La siguiente [expresión regular](https://www.debuggex.com/r/brlbblBKdPG2xoxq) tomará como válido si existe una palabra que al inicio de una frase dada y que al final contenga la letra «s».

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
^\w+s(?=\b)
```

Se puede utilizar de la siguiente forma:

```
if (preg_match('/^\w+s(?=\b)/i', $frase)) {
    echo "Las $frase";
} else {
    echo "La $frase";
}
```

#### Alternativa #2: dividir la cadena.

```
$palabras = explode(' ', $frase);
$primerPalabra = $palabras[0];

if (strrpos($primerPalabra, 's') === strlen($primerPalabra) - 1)) {
    echo "Las $frase";
} else {
    echo "La $frase";
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su comentario, de las dos formas que me explico cual seria la mas pesada de procesar.

Comment: @juanpablo sometí ambos ejercicios a un bucle de 100,000 iteraciones y el más tardado fue la alternativa #2.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. saludos

Answer (score 0):

Utilizaría la función `substr` con indice negativo para obtener el último caracter de la primera palabra separada por espacios con la función `explode`, el código queda mas limpio y legible.

```
$frase="respuesta en ingles";
if ( substr(explode($frase,' ')[0], -1, 1) == 's'){
    echo "La $frase";
} else {
    echo "Las $frase";
}
```

http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php